# Unable to execute the search page in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

Trying to execute the serachpage.jsp which can search out data from database on search id basis. Basically I'm getting an error after the select statement.

Code:

```
<%

try {
    String value = request.getParameter("Issue_ID");
    int Issue_ID=Integer.parseInt(value);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report_tracking","root", "root");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from issue_creating where Issue_ID='"+Issue_ID+"'");
    if(rs.next()) {         
        rs.getString("Problem_Submit");  
        rs.getString("Problem_Submit"); 
        rs.getString("Problem_Descr"); 
    }

%>
```

Error:

> An error occurred at line: [108] in the generated java file: [D:\mohit\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\work\Catalina\localhost_\org\‌​apache\jsp\serachisue_jsp.java]
>   Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement
>   An error occurred at line: [109] in the generated java file: [D:\mohit\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\work\Catalina\localhost_\org\‌​apache\jsp\serachisue_jsp.java]
>   Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: please treat it as urgent requirement if anyone can help me out as earliest as possible i'll be very thankful to him/her

Comment: can you add stack trace?

Comment: @shola i  dont't have any stack trace will provide the catalina log only because this local desktop application.

Comment: An error occurred at line: [108] in the generated java file: [D:\mohit\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\serachissue_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement

An error occurred at line: [109] in the generated java file: [D:\mohit\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\serachissue_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: hey check below answer you missed closing bracket of try block.

Answer (score 1):

} bracket missing for try block:

```
try { 
    String value = request.getParameter("Issue_ID"); int  Issue_ID = Integer.parseInt(value);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report_tracking","root", "root"); 
    Statement st = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from issue_creating where Issue_ID='"+Issue_ID+"'");     
    if(rs.next()) {
        rs.getString("Problem_Submit");
        rs.getString("Problem_Submit"); 
        rs.getString("Problem_Descr"); 
    }
} 
catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Getting the error after run the search.jsp program  java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
        at org.apache.jsp.serachissue_jsp._jspService(serachissue_jsp.java:83)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)

Comment: Issue_ID need to pass as request param : url?Issue_ID=100

Comment: how you passing Issue_ID in request?

Comment: select * from issue_creating where Issue_ID='1'";

Comment: browser url to invoke this jsp?

Comment: try with localhost:8081/serach.jsp?Issue_ID=1

Comment: what need to be change in the code part apart from your solution            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from issue_creating where Issue_ID='"+Issue_ID+"'");

Comment: In this code where i m executing a mysql select statement condition which can match the user enetered credential from database.if anything need to be change in my program code please let me know.

Comment: hi shola any conclusion for my query reagarding the same set of program.